# Contrasting color of overlay

Tags: android, overlay

I have an overlay rectangle that is always visible. If an "object" under the overlay is of the same color, my overlay won't be visually distinguishable - user may not realize where it is.
Is there a way to detect the color under the overlay so I can calculate and change color of my overlay to something that is contrasting ... ?

I could take a screenshot and find the position, calculate color but that would drain battery.
I don't want to have animation for the overlay because that can be too much distracting.

Do you have some ideas how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: so draw it with an outline drawn in different color - for example interior in white and outline in black

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with javascript:

```
<script>
    
       var e1 = document.getElementsByclassName("your_element")[0];
       var color1 = e1.style.backgroundColor;
    
       var e2 = document.getElementsByclassName("your_element2")[0];
       e2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    
</script>
```